# Can traefik rewrite the location header of redirect responses (302)

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I am using traefik 2.0.2 as reverse proxy in front of some services. One backend services is returning a redirect response (302), where the location header contains the absolute redirected url. The url of the backend is not reachable from the outside, how can I rewrite the location to go through the reverse proxy again?

E.g. a client requests `http://my-domain/foo` and receives a 302 response with location header containing `http://backend:8080/foo/bar/`, which of course will not work.

I am looking for something similar to [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) of apache mod_proxy. I have read through the available [middlewares](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/overview/) of traefik, but nothing seems to fit my requirement.

My simplified configuration:

```
# traefik.yml
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"

providers:
  file:
    filename: "dynamic-conf.yml"

# dynamic-conf.yml
http:
  routers:
    router1:
      entryPoints:
        - web
      service: service1
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/foo`)"
  services:
    service1
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://backend:8080
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did **not** find an option to rewrite the location header of a service response using traefik.
A feature request to [replaceResponseHeaders](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5809) exists.

My (temporary) solution is to perform the redirection in traefik using the [RedirectRegex](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/redirectregex/) middleware, such that the backend service does not need to response with a redirect.

The updated configuration would look like this:

```
# dynamic-conf.yml
http:
  routers:
    router1:
      entryPoints:
        - web
      service: service1
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/foo`)"
      middlewares:
        - my-redirect
  middlewares:
    my-redirect: # Workaround for service1 redirection
      redirectRegex:
        regex: "^https?://[^/]+/foo/?$"
        replacement: "/foo/webapp/"
  services:
    service1
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://backend:8080
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I needed this solution. Hope the feature request makes it through soon too

Comment: I added a bounty to this feature request. Join it to get this feature implemented sooner than later (see link in the feature request).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you, could not resolve it with your solution, but now, with the traefik plugins, we can:

Static config:

```yaml
pilot:
  token: "xxxx"

experimental:
  plugins:
    rewriteHeaders:
      modulename: "github.com/XciD/traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers"
      version: "v0.0.2"
```

Dynamic config:

```yaml
http:
  routes:
    my-router:
      rule: "Host(`localhost`)"
      service: "my-service"
      middlewares : 
        - "rewriteHeaders"
  services:
    my-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://127.0.0.1"
  middlewares:
    rewriteHeaders:
      plugin:
        rewriteHeaders:
          header: "Location"
          regex: "^http://(.+)$"
          replacement: "https://$1"
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin

Comment: could you elaborate on how to do that with container labels in a docker-compose file? I tried with `- "traefik.http.middlewares.rewriteRedirectHeaderHTTPS.rewriteheaders.header=Location"` and also regex and replacement and obviously `- "traefik.http.routi ers.somService.middlewares=rewriteRedirectHeaderHTTPS@file"` (or `@docker`) but get an error in the log stating `field not found, node: rewriteheaders" container=.... providerName=docker`

Comment: Hi @XciD. I create router rule: "Host(`{{env "LOCAL_NAME"}}`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)". Then a middleware with plugin
        rewriteHeaders:
          header: "Location"
          regex: "^http://{{env "LOCAL_NAME"}}/api/(.*)"
          replacement: "https://externalUrl/${1}"

Answer (score 0):

## Docker Traefik Provider Example

---

### Case

For example, in case a WebDav service is behind a TLS reverse-proxy (e.g. Traefik, port `443`), and the service itself is running on non-TLS protocol (i.e. port `80`), and renaming a file (i.e. HTTP method `MOVE`) in Nginx may result in error:

```
..."MOVE /dav/test.txt HTTP/1.1" 400...
...[error] 39#39: *4 client sent invalid "Destination" header...
```

Related: [Seafdav - MOVE command causing 502](https://forum.seafile.com/t/seafdav-move-command-causing-502/11582/23).

---

### Solution

#### Static (i.e. `traefik.yaml`)

```yaml
experimental:
  plugins:
    rewriteHeaders:
      modulename: 'github.com/bitrvmpd/traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers'
      version: 'v0.0.1'
```

#### Dynamic

```yaml
services:

  app:
    image: php

    volumes:
      - '/var/docker/data/app/config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro'
      - '/var/docker/data/app/data/:/var/www/'

    networks:
      reverse-proxy:

    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=80'

      # Replace 'Destination' request header: 'https://' -> 'http://'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.rewriteHeadersMW.plugin.traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers.rewrites.request[0].header=Destination'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.rewriteHeadersMW.plugin.traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers.rewrites.request[0].regex=^https://(.+)$'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.rewriteHeadersMW.plugin.traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers.rewrites.request[0].replacement=http://$1'

      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`sub.example.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.priority=2'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.middlewares=rewriteHeadersMW'

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    name: reverse-proxy
    external: true
```

---

Non-Traefik alternative: Nginx module [`headers-more-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module).

---

## Related

- [Traefik Plugin Page](https://plugins.traefik.io/plugins/63718c14c672f04dd500d1a0/rewrite-headers);
- [GitHub Plugin Page](https://github.com/bitrvmpd/traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers).